# How to distribute configurations across your node module

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

HI I am trying to create a node module for express. What I want is to get a config object from user at the time of initialization of the App. Then my app have many components/files which need to access the configuration object so that is the best way to manage this.
Regards

```
.
├── _index.js
├── _plans
|   ├── local.js
|   └── local2js
├── _models
|   ├── user.js
|   └── employee.js
```

I have my constructor in index.js and pass the config to all other files which are exposed to user via index.js

Comment: "*I have my constructor and pass the config to all other files*" - that sounds reasonable. What's the issue?